# C++ Getter Method Printing Weird Numbers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, getter

I suspect it's a problem with pointers, but I'm fairly new to C++ and I'm having some trouble debugging this. I have a *getX()* method in my Vector class I'm writing, but it never prints the int I pass in.

## `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector2.h"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    Vector2 vec2 = Vector2(5, 6);
    cout << vec2.getX() << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

## `Vector2.cpp`

```
#include "Vector2.h"`

Vector2::Vector2(int u, int v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    int x = u;
    int y = v;
}
int Vector2::getX() {
        return x;
}
int Vector2::getY() {
        return y;
}
Vector2::~Vector2() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
```

## `Vector2.h`

```
#ifndef VECTOR2_H_
#define VECTOR2_H_

class Vector2 {
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Vector2(int x, int y);
    int getX();
    int getY();
    virtual ~Vector2();
 };

#endif /* VECTOR2_H_ */
```

Comment: `int x = u; int y = v;` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Vector2::Vector2(int u, int v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    int x = u;
    int y = v;
}
```

The constructor updates local variables instead of class members. Try

```
Vector2::Vector2(int u, int v) {
    x = u;
    y = v;
}
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. Thanks, I've spent a couple scratching my head and 20 seconds to fix it. I appreciate the help!